# How to return []byte from internal void * in C function by CGO?

Tags: go, cgo

I am wrapping an C function with the following definition:

```
int parser_shift(parser* parser, void* buffer, int length);
```

It removes up to length bytes from internal buffer of unparsed bytes, storing them in the given buffer.

Now I wish to wrap it into a Go function with the following definition:

```
func (p *Parser) Shift() []byte {
    var buffer []byte
    // TODO:

    return buffer
}
```

What is the right way of writing to finish the TODO in above with CGO?

I tried the following way, however it crashed with error: Error in "/path/to/my/program': free(): invalid next size (fast): 0x00007f8fe0000aa0:

```
var buffer []byte
bufStr := C.CString(string(buffer))
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(bufStr))
C.parser_shift(p.Cparser, unsafe.Pointer(bufStr), C.int(8192))
buffer = []byte(C.GoString(bufStr))
return buffer
```

Comment: is the buffer empty?

Comment: you are not supposed to pass string type to c, use `C.CBytes()`, instead of creating `BufStr` and passing it.

Comment: @nilsocket yes you are right, I wasn't sure about it is the right way of writing. The C function returns buffer via void*buffer, which is something I wish to receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your `parser_shift` function returns the number of bytes actually stored in the buffer, you can do something like this:

```
func (p *Parser) Shift() []byte {
    var buffer [8192]byte
    parsed := int(C.parser_shift(p.Cparser, unsafe.Pointer(&buffer[0]), C.int(len(buffer))))
    return buffer[:parsed]
}
```

There is no need to convert to or from string, just pass it the memory that you want it to write to.

Comment: Thank you! Is it safe for garbage collection? is buffer under the Go GC control?

Comment: It is safe, as long as you do not keep a pointer to this buffer in your C code you will have no problems. Your buffer is in Go, you just let C write to it for a while.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```golang
// C pointer, length to Go []byte
func C.GoBytes(unsafe.Pointer, C.int) []byte
```